# Split character string forward slash and in brackets

Tags: r, split, tidyverse, stringr

I would split a character string which consist of data look like this: 105/44(64)
I would split this in 3 columns:

- "105" called "systole"
- "44" called "diastole"
- "64" called "map"

How can I do that?
I have not enough capacity to extract this out the other questions about split strings...
I think I have to do it with stringr from tidyverse?

Answer (score 0):

Using `strsplit` on non-digits `\\D`. No packages needed.

```
strsplit(x, '\\D', perl=TRUE) |>
  do.call(what=rbind.data.frame) |>
  setNames(c('systole', 'diastole', 'map'))
#   systole diastole map
# 1     105       44  64
# 2     106       43  61
```

W/o pipes:

```
setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, strsplit(x, '\\D', perl=TRUE)), 
         c('systole', 'diastole', 'map'))
#   systole diastole map
# 1     105       44  64
# 2     106       43  61
```

---

*Data:*

```
x <- c('105/44(64)', '106/43(61)')
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can make use of `read.csv/read.table` after creating a common delimiter

```
read.csv(text = trimws(gsub("[[:punct:]]", ",", str1), whitespace= ","), 
   header = FALSE, col.names = c("systole", "diastole", "map"))
```

-output

```
   systole diastole map
1     105       44  64
2     106       43  61
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c('105/44(64)', '106/43(61)')
```